# Segmentation fault when running C code with MPI library

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

I am running this code on a Linux system:

```
// mpic++ -o lab lab.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 3 // розмір топології Гіперкуб

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int size, rank;
    double *A, *B, *C, *subA, *subC, *subB;
    int n = 500; // розмір матриць
    int sub_n;   // розмір підматриць
    int i, j, k;
    double start_time, end_time;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // розмір підматриці для кожного процесу
    sub_n = n / size;

    // розбиття матриць A та B на підматриці для кожного процесу
    subA = (double *)malloc(sub_n * n * sizeof(double));
    subB = (double *)malloc(sub_n * sizeof(double));
    subC = (double *)calloc(sub_n * n, sizeof(double));

    // ініціалізація матриць A та B
    for (i = 0; i < sub_n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            subA[i * n + j] = (1.85 * sqrt((rank * sub_n + i) + sin(j))) / (cos((rank * sub_n + i) + j) + 5);
        }
        subB[i] = (double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX / 40.0) / 4.0;
    }

    // ініціалізація топології "гіперкуб"
    int dims[N];
    int periods[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        dims[i] = 2;    // кількість вузлів у кожному напрямку
        periods[i] = 1; // періодичність
    }
    MPI_Comm comm;
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, N, dims, periods, 1, &comm);

    // розрахунок координат поточного процесу в топології
    int coords[N];
    MPI_Cart_coords(comm, rank, N, coords);

    // розрахунок сусідніх процесів у топології
    int source[N], dest[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        MPI_Cart_shift(comm, i, 1, &source[i], &dest[i]);
    }

    // паралельне множення матриць
    MPI_Barrier(comm);
    start_time = MPI_Wtime();

    // кожен процес виконує обчислення своєї частини підматриці C
    for (i = 0; i < sub_n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < sub_n; k++)
            {
                subC[i * n + j] += subA[i * n + k] * B[k * n + j];
            }
        }
    }

    // обмін даними між процесами для збору результатів в матрицю C
    MPI_Datatype row;
    MPI_Type_contiguous(n, MPI_DOUBLE, &row);
    MPI_Type_commit(&row);

    // кожен процес відправляє свою підматрицю C до головного процесу
    if (rank != 0)
    {
        MPI_Send(subC, sub_n * n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, comm);
    }
    else
    {
        // головний процес отримує підматриці C від інших процесів та збирає їх в матрицю C
        C = (double *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
        for (i = 0; i < sub_n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                C[i * n + j] = subC[i * n + j];
            }
        }
        for (k = 1; k < size; k++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(subC, sub_n * n, MPI_DOUBLE, k, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            for (i = 0; i < sub_n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    C[(k * sub_n + i) * n + j] = subC[i * n + j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(comm);
    end_time = MPI_Wtime();

    // виведення результату
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("Multiplication time: %f seconds\n", end_time - start_time);

        // виведення матриці C
        printf("Matrix C:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                printf("%f ", C[i * n + j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    // завершення програми та звільнення пам'яті
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    free(subA);
    free(subB);
    free(subC);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

The terminal outputs the following:

```
lab5:8061 terminated with signal 11 at PC=561d993e5815 SP=7ffef0233730.  Backtrace:
./lab5(+0x1815)[0x561d993e5815]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90)[0x7f16bb029d90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80)[0x7f16bb029e40]
./lab5(+0x1365)[0x561d993e5365]

lab5:8062 terminated with signal 11 at PC=560003f0e815 SP=7ffd29e58150.  Backtrace:
./lab5(+0x1815)[0x560003f0e815]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90)[0x7f9594829d90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80)[0x7f9594829e40]
./lab5(+0x1365)[0x560003f0e365]

===================================================================================
BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
PID 8060 RUNNING AT Ubuntu1
EXIT CODE: 9
CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Killed (signal 9)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

How to solve it?

Comment: In C++ you use `new\delete` instead of `malloc\free`

Comment: you do not need to declare all variables in the beginning. Afaik this is/was required in C or conisdered "good style", not in c++. Prefer to declare variables only when you can initialize them

Comment: @metablaster small correction: in C++ you use `std::vector` rather than manual dynamic arrays (unless there is a reason not to)

Comment: *how to solve it?* -- There is no error checking to see if `malloc` failed.  There is also no diganostic output to see what exactly the values are that you are using.  For example `size`, `sub_n`, etc.  This code shows little to no debugging effort.

Comment: Try with your debugger. You'll most likely get more information that allows you to diagnostic the problem.

Comment: What input are you giving the program?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number a requirement of ANSI C (i.e. C89, but fell out of favor in C99 iirc).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>                subC[i * n + j] += subA[i * n + k] * B[k * n + j];
> ```

Here you are dereferencing `B` without ever having allocated memory to it.

You would have been notified about this error had you compiled with `-Wall`.